# Rename file name before sharing application through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a share Button for my app that it will share my entire application through Intent.. It works like this:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    File srcFile = new File(ai.publicSourceDir);

    Intent share = new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(srcFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "PersianCoders"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ShareApp", e.getMessage());
}
```

Now this will send my application with my package name.. I need to rename it with my application name before sharing.. Like this for example:

```
PackageManager packageManager= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
String shareName =   appName+"_"+"v"+version;
```

Is there a way to rename my package name with this "shareName" String ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CommonsWare mentioned,You can do it by creating a backup of your application into a path ,then share it from that path:

```
public void shareApp(String package_name) {
try {
    PackageManager packageManager= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
    packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
    String shareName =   appName+"_"+"v"+version;               

    File f1;
    File f2 = null;
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List<?> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    for (Object object : pkgAppsList) {
    ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals(package_name)) {
    f1 = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
    try {
    f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Apps");
    f2.mkdirs();
    f2 = new File(f2.getPath() + "/" + shareName + ".apk");
    f2.createNewFile();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("File copied.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
   } 
  }
    Intent share = new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f2));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "PersianCoders"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ShareApp", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And call it wherever you like:

```
shareApp(getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to rename my package name with this "shareName" String ?

Not directly. There is no "use this alternative filename" option in `ACTION_SEND`.

You can:

- Make a copy of the original file, under the new filename, and share that copy, or
- Implement a `ContentProvider`, one that returns the file's content when it receives a `Uri` with the new filename

The latter is more complex but also solves your `Uri.fromFile()` problem: that will not work once you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher, when running on an Android 7.0+ device.